# Android - "hello tab widget" generates 3 app files

Tags: android, layout, tabs, apk, tabwidget

I run the simple examples in the android dev site of tab widget:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

My problem is that after I export the project to .apk file, and install it on my phone
I get 3 app launchers.

I tried to use different .xml file to each activity but it didn't help.

I'll be happy to some ideas!

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have an Activity defined in the [manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) file for each of the tab activities, as well as the HelloTabWidget itself! (See the Activities topic in the [Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html))

Comment: The solution is to remove the 'intent-filter' tag from the tabs class.

Comment: Thanks -- yes, that is important too!

Comment: (You don't want them in the launcher category or set as main actions.)